# How do I use a dynamic role password in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a role in postgres as follows:

`create role admin login password 'some_password';`

What I'd like instead is:

`create role admin login (select current_setting('custom.ADMIN_PASSWORD'));`

But this fails with the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2: (SELECT ...
```

I expected this to work, because it works in the following example:

```
select public.register_account(
    email := (SELECT current_setting('custom.SOME_EMAIL')),
    password := (SELECT current_setting('custom.SOME_PASSWORD'))
);
```

How  can I use `current_setting()` to apply a role password?

Bonus Points: Why does my first example fail, while my second succeeds?

Answer (score 1):

The first failed because DDL changes like that aren't your general everyday SQL. Think of a statement like the creation of a role as being special within the context of PostgreSQL. In general the database engine prefers DDL and other structural changes to be explicit, not calculated on the fly like a lot of the rest of SQL.

You can however get around this restriction by using a "do" block, essentially an inline function. Combined with the `EXECUTE` command and the `format()` function, you can go dynamic to your heart's content. Only be warned that with great power comes great responsibility. Dynamic SQL like this should be avoided in general unless you truly have no other alternative since it short circuits a lot of the grammar/parser validation. Simple mistakes become a lot harder to see and fix while at the same time—due to it being a structural change to the database rather than just another row of data—far more serious in effect when bugs arise. Many tasks like `CREATE ROLE` do not allow dynamic shenanigans by default precisely for this reason.

All that said, this will get you going.

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('CREATE ROLE admin LOGIN PASSWORD ''%1$s'';',
                 current_setting('custom.ADMIN_PASSWORD'));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Your solution worked for me, and understanding the reason for this class of errors is really valuable.

Comment: @CBFay don't forget to mark the accepted answer.